# Watson Personality Insights API rate limit

Tags: watson, personality-insights

In their Documentation they have not mention any api limit as 6 per minutes and when I actually started hitting the api continuously I was able to hit 10 api per min. What's the issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you want to find out?

Comment: This might be better asked/answered by opening a ticket in bluemix.